# Get OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory at calling pdfdump() of PyX

Tags: python-2.7, scapy

Python 2.7
Scapy 2.4

I tried to run pdfdump() demo of scapy but get OSError like following:

`/>>> a=rdpcap("/home/zhangqiang/test.pcap")
/>>> a
<test.pcap: TCP:1053 UDP:4 ICMP:0 Other:0>`

**`/>>> a[423].pdfdump(layer_shift=1)`**

I got error like following

`ERROR: pdfdump(): executing 'acroread' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zhangqiang/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 526, in pdfdump
    subprocess.Popen([conf.prog.pdfreader, fname])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I googled this problem, It is said that Module shlex is required.
so I has imported the module, but the other error has been raised.
As if the TeX is not work.

**`/>>> import shlex`**

`/>>> a[423].pdfdump(layer_shift=1)`

```
still waiting for tex after 5 of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 10 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 15 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 20 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 25 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 30 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 35 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 40 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 45 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 50 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 55 (of 60) seconds...
the timeout of 60 seconds expired and tex did not respond.
We try to finish the dvi due to an unhandled tex error
still waiting for tex after 5 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 10 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 15 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 20 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 25 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 30 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 35 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 40 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 45 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 50 (of 60) seconds...
still waiting for tex after 55 (of 60) seconds...
the timeout of 60 seconds expired and tex did not respond.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/zhangqiang/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 521, in pdfdump
    canvas = self.canvas_dump(**kargs)
  File "/home/zhangqiang/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 635, in canvas_dump
    pt = pyx.text.text(XSTART, (YTXT-y)*YMUL, r"\font\cmssfont=cmss10\cmssfont{%s}" % proto.name, [ pyx.text.size.Large])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyx/text.py", line 1201, in text
    raise e
TexResultError: TeX didn't respond as expected within the timeout period (60 seconds).
The expression passed to TeX was:
  \ProcessPyXBox{\Large{}\font\cmssfont=cmss10\cmssfont{Ethernet}%
  }{82}%
  \PyXInput{86}%
After parsing the return message from TeX, the following was left:
  \*! Interruption.
  <*>

  ? Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
  R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
  (cut after 5 lines, increase errordebug for more output)
```

How I fix this problem?

Comment: `executing 'acroread' failed [..] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Seems pretty clear? You don't have the `acroread` program installed (which I presume is Acrobat Reader?)

Comment: thanks, I understanded. indeed I have not installed Acrobat Reader.Thanks. I tried to install  Acrobat Reader. but Acrobat Reader did't support Unbuntu 1.7 and later More. 
Anyway Thanks your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You must set `conf.prog.pdfreader` to the program you want to use to open PDF files. For example: `conf.prog.pdfreader = "evince"`.